# Data layer as WCF vs an in app data layer

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am working on an app which uses WCF as data layer.

I understand there as certain benefits such as security. What would be other benefits or handicaps in such approach?

Isn't serializing and de-serializing would cost performance?

how about maintenance, testing and maintainability?

What would be other drawbacks of such approach?

Comment: I don't undestand what you mean by `WCF as data layer`. WCF is an IPC mechanism. It's not designed to increase your application's security or performance for that matter.

Comment: ok Einstein, if an attacker gains access to app server, he/she doesn't have direct access to your database? would that be a reason?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure putting the SQL strings in the `Button1_Click` in the `Form1` code behind will somehow magically manifest in more testability and maintainability. What are you talking about?

Comment: The cost of using WCF usually is not related to where it is applied. Testability depends on how you design the layers to interact with each other i.e by contract and based on abstraction. The other issues are not directly related to WCF.

Comment: @MoreCrazy until there's a need to use the application in more than 1 machine and have a server with N clients...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a data layer and it is accessed using WCF.  First the upside to this: you can move your data layer wherever you need it and your applications should not care.  (as long as the dns resolves correctly)  And if it is hosted inside IIS then you gain some security by doing SLL as your secured layer in front of your service.  And if your services are well written you can easily throw them into a load balanced process.

On the downside you need to be concerned about how you expose that service.  If it communicates the data back in XML you will suffer a much larger serialization penalty than if you used JSON as your means of serializing data.

In the middle side of things (neither good or bad) you would be forcing yourself to be careful (I would hope) in how you format your requests.  For example, passing only a key for a delete instead of the entire record to delete.  (believe me, I've seen systems written like this!!)

You should also carefully design your services so that your svc file contains something like this:

```
   public Customer GetCustomer(int customerID)
   {
         return DataLayer.GetCustomer(customerID);
   }
```

This way you can easily directly utilize your datalayer if some other application is already sitting on your WCF server.  A good example of this is you may have your data layer isolated inside your internal network.  Sheltered by the DMZ.  Your intranet may need to access the same data layer so you can put your intranet applications on that server and directly use the datalayer.  Or they can be on a different server but use the data layer libraries directly.

One final note...which we encountered a need for in one situation.  If you implement something out on the DMZ that needs to directly access a server instead of being routed through the firewalls, you can easily create a proxy of your data services.  The proxy just takes your service interface and implements calls through the firewall to your service behind the DMZ.  Took us maybe one day to implement this.

For testing: well that is no different than anywhere else you have a data layer.  You need to do your tests, use repeatable data in your test setup, and proper cleanup after your tests complete.   It also does not change for maintainability, etc.  However you need to have a clear approach for versioning of your services to encompass interface changes.  But, again, that is the same no matter where your data services lie.

Hope this helps some.